# How do I override the controller name for a rails url helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `Post` model with a `category` attribute and corresponding `PostsController`.

I would like to override the default url helper to produce the folowing:

```
@post = Post.create(category: 'posts')
<%= link_to 'Post Link', @post %>
# /posts/1

@post = Post.create(category: 'articles')
<%= link_to 'Article Link', @post %>
# /articles/2
```

I would like to call the default url helper for `Post` but have it create different urls based upon the `category` column.

**Update**

I ended up overriding the url helpers:

```
module PostsHelper
  def post_path(post, options={})
    self.send("#{post.category}_path", post, options)
  end

  def post_url(post, options={})
    self.send("#{post.category}_url", post, options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Named Routes is what you want:

`get 'posts/:id', to: 'posts#<controller-action>', as: 'posts'`

`<%= link_to 'Post Link', posts_path(@post) %>`

`get 'articles/:id', to: 'posts#<controller-action>', as: 'articles'`

`<%= link_to 'Article Link', articles_path(@post) %>`

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

Comment: I want to the call `posts_path` for both objects and have the `category` attribute determine which url is displayed.

Comment: Could you show your posts model, schema and controller? It's not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: For this example `Post` has only one column `category`, and the controller is the default generated by a scaffold for example.